# Only setting the attribute in wrong shader program affects attribute value

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm running always into problems, as soon as I try to use more than one shader program in OpenGL. For some reason, setting the attribute of my shader2 program in use is not reflecting at all - but setting the attribute in the currently not used shader1, affects rendering in shader2. I'm sure, that my shader2 is used (setting the attribute inside shader to a constant value reflects on objects drawn with shader2), and that I'm setting the attribute value in shader2.

I encapsuled the ShaderPrograms into a class like:

```
class ShaderProgram{
public:
ShaderProgram(const std::string& vertexSource, const std::string& fragmentSource){
  vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  const GLchar *source = (const GLchar *)vertexSource.c_str();
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &source, 0);
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  source = (const GLchar *)fragmentSource.c_str();
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &source, 0);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  program = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(program);
}
void use(){
  glUseProgram(program);
}
void setAttribPointer(const char* name, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const void* pointer) {
  GLuint pos = glGetAttribLocation(program, name);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
  glVertexAttribPointer(pos, size, type, normalized, stride, pointer);
}
void setAttribValue4f(const char* name, float x, float y, float z, float w) {
  GLuint pos = glGetAttribLocation(program, name);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(pos);
  const GLfloat pointer[] = { x, y, z, w };
  glVertexAttrib4fv(program, pointer);
}
~ShaderProgram() {
  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
  glDeleteProgram(program);
}
private:
 GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader, program;
};
```

And the renderloop in my application looks like:

```
program1.use();
program1.setAttribValue4f("color", 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
program1.setAttribPointer("positions", 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices.data());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices.data());
program2.use();
program2.setAttribValue4f("color", 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
program2.setAttribPointer("positions", 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices.data());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices.data());
```

In this case, both objects are drawn in red - while the second should be blue (color attribute is set to blue in second shader program). I can reproduce this problem with any simple GLSL shader. However, if I change the above code to:

```
program1.use();
program1.setAttribValue4f("color", 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
program1.setAttribPointer("positions", 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices.data());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices.data());
program2.use();
program1.setAttribValue4f("color", 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
program2.setAttribPointer("positions", 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices.data());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices.data());
```

the second object is drawn in blue (which is what I want to accomplish). But whats confussing is, that `glVertexAttrib4fv(program, pointer);` is called on the wrong program object (which is not used), but color is changed - while it's not changing, if I'm using the correct program object (program2). I checked `glGetError()` after `glUseProgram()` and after `glGetAttribLocation()`/`glVertexAttrib4fv()` - always returning 0. The location returned by `glGetAttribLocation()` is also correct.
GLSL is `#version 330`

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem in a simple typing mistake. As first parameter I'm passing the program object to `glVertexAttrib4fv()` instead of the location:

```
glVertexAttrib4fv(program, pointer);
```

should've been:

```
glVertexAttrib4fv(pos, pointer);
```

The fact that OpenGL is using weak-typing (the same type `GLuint` for completly different objects), made it hard to find this mistake. Coincidentally the location of my attribute was the value as the first program (`GLuint` with value 1), which causes to use always the attributes I've set in the first program (because ther eprogram was equal to the location I wanted to set). Fixing this, solved the issue for me.

It's important to keep in mind, that 
there is no direct relationship between VertexAttributes and Shader programs - the [the specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml) says:

> The binding between a generic vertex attribute index and a
>   user-defined attribute variable in a vertex shader is part of the
>   state of a program object, but the current value of the generic vertex
>   attribute is not. The value of each generic   vertex attribute is part
>   of current state and it is maintained even if a different program
>   object is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to set a per-vertex color then use a uniform to pass the value.

Also why call glDisableVertexAttribArray(pos) in setAttribValue4f?

Comment: Usually I'm using colors per-vertex, but there is also the case that all vertexes shall have same color so I call `glDisableVertexAttribArray()` to disable the VertexAttributePointer and setting the constant value using `glVertexAttrib4fv()` to it. Otherwise I would need to build a giant color array with all values identical, which seems to be a memory waste to me. Using a uniform would only be applicable, when always a constant value for the color is used - here I used constant values to better illustrate the problem with a more compact mcve which can reproduce the problem.